# Autocomplete Jquery to the textbox in GridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, jquery-autocomplete

I wish to add autocomplete feature to the textvox in my grid, However, I'm unable to call the textbox from the Script.

The HTML code is

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:GridView ID="grdUserTrans" CellSpacing="1" runat="server" 
Width="100%">                                                                
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="ID" SortExpression="ID" 
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Register Number" DataField="REGNO" 
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="USERNAME" 
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stop Name" ControlStyle-CssClass="radionobrdr"
ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="txtClass" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox">  
</asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField></Columns></asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=grdUserTrans.ClientID%>").find(".TextBox").autocomplete('Search_CS.ashx');
});       
</script>
```

The Search_CS file is

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data;

public class Search_CS : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT KSM_STOP_NAME FROM KSL_STOP_MST WHERE
 KSM_STOP_NAME LIKE '%" + prefixText + "%'";
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        sb.Append(sdr["KSM_STOP_NAME"])
                            .Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            }
        }

}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

The connection String is

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=KACPER-SERVER;Initial  
Catalog=KED_MACAULAY;Integrated Security=false;uid=KACPER_SQL;pwd=KACPER_SQL123;
pooling=true;connect timeout=900;max pool size=200"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: There is an alternate solution for this using AjaxToolKit AutoComplete. have you tried that? It is quite easy to implement.

Comment: Note for those reviewing, this uses the older autocomplete plug-in, NOT the jQuery UI autocomplete.

Comment: @Ashwini Verma yes, I have used the Ajax toolkit, but It provides autocomplete to the first row in the grid alone. This Jquery autocomplete seemed easy so thought of giving this one a try

Comment: Thanks guys...found the code..The script code should be like this

    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("*[id$=grdUserTrans]    
    input[id$=txtClass]").autocomplete('Search_CS.ashx');  
    
    });         
    </script>

Comment: The script code should be like this 


    <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("*[id$=grdUserTrans] 
    input[id$=txtClass]").autocomplete('Search_CS.ashx'); }); 
    </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys...found the code..The script code should be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $("*[id$=grdUserTrans] 
input[id$=txtClass]").autocomplete('Search_CS.ashx'); }); </script>
```